# restrict jqgrid from auto-refreshing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using **struts2-jquery-jqgrid**. I am having **filterSearch** on the grid. Here in filter I have a drop-down list on column **Assigned To** containing the list of users, and based on the users,data can be filtered.

**Problem Scenario:**

When I select an option from drop-down list data is filtered successfully but after that **jqgrid is automatically getting refreshed**. So, again I can not get the filtered data in the grid.

**My grid is**

```
    <sjg:grid
            id="gridtable"
            caption="Issue-Summary"
            dataType="json"
            href="%{remoteurl}"
            pager="true"
            gridModel="finalGridModel"
            rowList="20,25,30"
            rowNum="20"
            rownumbers="true"
            width="1260" 
            filter="true"
            filterOptions="{stringResult :true,
                            searchOnEnter : true,
                            enableClear : true,
**// Update Section**       autosearch:'false' //this solved my problem
                           }"   
        >
            <sjg:gridColumn name="assigned_to"   index="assigned_user" key="assigned_user" title="Assigned To" searchtype="select"
              searchoptions="{defaultSearch:'cn', dataUrl : '%{fillUser}', 
              dataEvents: [{ type: 'change', fn: function(elem) { myfunction(elem)}}]}"/>
       </sjg:grid>
```

Snapshot of my grid

[image]

Any Help would be great.

Comment: You have not option in the code that enables it autorefreshing.

Comment: I mean, jqgrid is automatically getting refreshed, are you getting wht I am trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I made it working,just I had to add **autosearch:'false'** 
plese check the updated section